# MYSQL : Grouping rows by dates and making fields in to column names

Tags: mysql, group-by

Have have table like this

```
id   date         user   call_count
﻿1    2020-09-15   Tim    4
2    2020-09-14   Tim    6
3    2020-09-04   Jamie  1
4    2020-09-02   Tim    2
5    2020-09-07   Tim    5
6    2020-09-01   Jamie  1
7    2020-09-01   Tim    5
8    2020-09-10   Jamie  4
9    2020-09-12   Tim    5
10   2020-09-22   Tim    44
11   2020-09-22   Tony   32
```

I'd like to have a single query that groups by date, putting each user as the name of a column and displaying their count for that date. Right now I am accomplishing this by a few loops of selects, but it is ugly and not efficient.
Result should look like

```
Date        Tim  Tony  Jamie
2020-09-22  44   32 
2020-09-15  4       
2020-09-14  6       
2020-09-12  5       
2020-09-10              4
2020-09-07  5       
2020-09-04              1
2020-09-02  2       
2020-09-01  5           1
```

I've searched quite a bit for something like this, but not finding much. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user = 'Tim'   THEN call_count END) AS Tim,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user = 'Tony'  THEN call_count END) AS Tony,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user = 'Jamie' THEN call_count END) AS Jamie
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Date
ORDER BY
    Date;
```